# Limit HTTP request rate for spray/akka-http

Tags: scala, http, akka

I want to limit the request rate in a spray/akka-http route. I'm not an expert with both scala and spray/akka but learning. So I came up with the following custom directive:

```
  trait RequestRateLimiter[T] {
    def check(ctx: RequestContext, realIp: Option[RemoteAddress], proxiedIp: Option[RemoteAddress]) : RequestRateResult[T]
  }

  sealed trait RequestRateResult[T]
  case class Pass[T](result: T) extends RequestRateResult[T]
  case class Block[T](rejection: Rejection) extends RequestRateResult[T]

  def limit[T](requestRateLimiter: RequestRateLimiter[T]): Directive1[T] = {
    def remoteAddress: Directive1[Option[RemoteAddress]] = optionalHeaderValuePF { case `Remote-Address`(address) ⇒ address }
    def xForwardedFor: Directive1[Option[RemoteAddress]] = optionalHeaderValuePF { case `X-Forwarded-For`(Seq(address, _*)) ⇒ address }
    extract(identity) flatMap { ctx =>
      remoteAddress.flatMap { realIp =>
        xForwardedFor.flatMap { proxiedIp =>
          requestRateLimiter.check(ctx, realIp, proxiedIp) match {
            case Pass(result)     => provide(result)
            case Block(rejection) => reject(rejection)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The custom directive takes an instance of an `RequestRateLimiter` which keeps track of the request rate based on the `RequestContext` and `RemoteAddress`. The `RequestRateLimiter` then decides if the request should be passed or blocked.
I'm not quiet happy with the `RequestRateLimiter` because it's too generic. It can be anything that either provides something or rejects.

I also posted [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/TobiasPfeifer/b0a5bda9949659682d4b) (feel free to share, use and improve).

What do you think of the directive? Anything that could be improved?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question

Comment: It looks to me like you could replace your suite of flatMap by a for comprehension. It would make it more readable, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could rewrite your limit function like this :

```
def limit[T](requestRateLimiter: RequestRateLimiter[T]) = {
  def remoteAddress = optionalHeaderValuePF { case `Remote-Address`(address) ⇒ address }
  def xForwardedFor = optionalHeaderValuePF { case `X-Forwarded-For`(Seq(address, _*)) ⇒ address }

  for {
    ctx <- extract(identity)
    realIp <- remoteAddress
    proxiedIp <- xForwardedFor
  } yield requestRateLimiter.check(ctx, realIp, proxiedIp) match {
    case Pass(result) => provide(result)
    case Block(rejection) => reject(rejection)
  }
}
```

Here are the two main changes that I've done :

1. Changed your flatMaps for a "for comprehension" (which imho is more readable)
2. Removed the types on the declaration of the two variables.

Overall, I find it more readable.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using in some cases the Akka Throttling module and seems to be a very good solution when you want to limit some resources. I think you don't have to implement a custom directive for that, think on your code and try to adapt a throttling to control that.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/contrib/throttle.html

**EDIT**

Well, I would use the throttle in an actor instead.

eg:

```
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp

object Main extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
  val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "my-actor")
  val throttler = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[TimerBasedThrottler], 3 msgsPer 1.second))
  throttler ! SetTarget(Some(myActor))

  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
    path("hello") {
      get {
        complete(throttler ! "Hello World!!!)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A clear example with the code of OP would go a long way here. At Code Review, we want to help OP get better and write better code.  While suggestion are valid answer, a clear example would help op better.

Comment: ah cool @Marc-Andre I will edit that ASAP providing some example using the throttling. Thanks

Comment: I like this idea, but I don't know if it is powerful enough for what I'm trying to do. I wrote the directive because I want to have different limitations for different resources (or even no limitations at all). Furthermore It has to be limited per IP-Address (or other extractions from the context). I know that spray/akka-http is based on akka actors but don't know how to instrument these actors.